# A Function That is Always Less Than 1

Tags: functions

I am working on a calculus problem which has led me to try to define a "simple" function, say $f$, that is always strictly less than 1, for any $x$, i.e., $f(x) < 1$.

Similarly, I am trying to find a function, $g(x)$, that is always greater than 1 for all $x$.

I am not sure where to start. Note that: constant functions are not allowed.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Wouldn't $f(x)=0$ be an example of the first kind, and $g(x) = 2$ an example of the second kind? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Sorry, I amended my question. We are not allowed to use constant functions!

Comment: The choose $f(x) = -x^2$ and $g(x) = 2+x^2$

Comment: @MartinR, great minds think alike, I was just about to post the **exact** same examples!

Comment: You said: *“I am working on a calculus problem”* – So this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/196432). May I suggest that you post the actual problem that you are working on?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = -x^2$ will work; I came up with $f(x) = -x^2$ by drawing a graph and plotting common polynomials. For $g(x)$, $g(x) = x^2 + 1$ will work, since $x^2 \geq 0$, so that $x^2+1\geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

To find a function always greater than 1, just get a function with even powers and add a constant that is greater than 1 at the end. For example, $x^4+1$ . 
To find a function that is always less than 1, take the negative of a function that is always greater than 1. This will reflect your function through the x axis. For example $-(x^4 +1)$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can enjoy the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}, \qquad x\in \mathbb{R}
$$
[image]